# How to handle paths and working directory in Python

Tags: python

I have the following folder structure:

```
 - Project
      - Main Folder
          - Module.py
      - Other Folders
          - blah.py
```

Launching the following code from the module `Module.py` provides two ways to get the working directory and it seems that they are equivalent:

```
pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()

pathlib.Path.cwd()
```

What are the differences (pros & cons) in using one way over the other?

Comment: Personally I would use the build in `os` module.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly they are pretty much the same.

If you check the [source code](https://pykeen.readthedocs.io/en/v1.1.0/_modules/pathlib.html) of pathlib. You can see `pathlib.Path.cwd()` just returns os.

```py
    def cwd(cls):
        """Return a new path pointing to the current working directory
        (as returned by os.getcwd()).
        """
        return cls(os.getcwd())
```

And `pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()` the same with some additional validations.

```py
    def resolve(self, path, strict=False):
        s = str(path)
        if not s:
            return os.getcwd()
        previous_s = None
        if _getfinalpathname is not None:
            if strict:
                return self._ext_to_normal(_getfinalpathname(s))
            else:
                tail_parts = []  # End of the path after the first one not found
                while True:
                    try:
                        s = self._ext_to_normal(_getfinalpathname(s))
                    except FileNotFoundError:
                        previous_s = s
                        s, tail = os.path.split(s)
                        tail_parts.append(tail)
                        if previous_s == s:
                            return path
                    else:
                        return os.path.join(s, *reversed(tail_parts))
        # Means fallback on absolute
        return None
```